# rendering issue after going to Android Studio 2.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After migrating over to Android Studio 2.1 I can't render xml files.  It says...

Android N Requires the IDE to be running with Java 1.8 or later
Install a supported JDK.

But that doesn't make any sense because...
1. I'm not specifying "N".
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
2. My project structure says I AM running Java 1.8 pointing my JDK location to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_25
So what is wrong?
Thanks,
Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting myself from Version 7.3 of [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android):

> You may get a "Rendering Problems" overlay, atop the preview pane:

[image: "Rendering Problems" in Android Studio]

> This is commonplace with Android Studio. In this case, look on the toolbar
>   above the preview area. In the screenshot shown above, you will notice that
>   the right-hand element in that toolbar is the green "bugdroid" mascot,
>   followed by "N" and a drop-down arrow. This indicates that the layout preview
>   is attempting to use the rules for the N Developer Preview, and that
>   apparently has bugs. Switch that drop-down value to something else, 
>   such as "23", which should clear up the "Rendering Problems" issue.

Comment: I've got 6.4.  Hard to keep up.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

never met such problem. you may want to click File->Project Stucture->SDK Location to set JDK as 1.8. hope this helps.

[image]